# Props is not defined on contentComponent in react navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to add an Logout button on my drawer, so i have used contentComponent in order to custom create logout alone ( not other drawer menu ). So , i have created a class and trying to receive DrawerItems but it says props not defined. Kindly help.

My Code Custom Component:

```
 class DrawerComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    console.log(this.props)
  }

render () {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
                <DrawerItems {props.children} />
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("Pressed")}>
                    <Text>
                    Logout
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </View>
    );
  }
 };
```

My Drawer Options:

```
 const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
Dashboard: {
  screen: AppStackNavigator,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: "Home",
  }
},
Training: {
  screen: Training,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: "Training"
  }
},
RoutePlan: {
  screen: RouteCalendar,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: "Route Plan"
  }
},
Logout: {
  screen: StoreList,
  navigationOptions: {
    drawerLabel: "Logout"
  }
}
},
{
contentOptions: {
  activeTintColor: '#127CC1',
},
contentComponent: props => <DrawerComponent {...props}/>,
drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle',
navigationOptions : ({navigation}) => {
  const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
  const headerTitle = routeName;
  return {
      headerTitle,
      headerLeft: (
        <Icon name="md-menu" style={{ marginLeft: 10 }} 
        onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
        />
      )
    }
  }
}
);
```

Am getting error on my customComponent page. Kindly help me to get through !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `render` method for the `DrawerComponent`, you are calling `props.children`. In that case, `props` has not been defined within the render method. You could define it with a line like `let props = this.props` at the start of the render method,  or just call `this.props` instead of the bare `props`.

If you used a functional component instead, you wouldn't need to get `props` from `this`, and would instead get it as the argument to your functional component:

```js
function FooComponent(props){
  return (<div style={{color:"#F00"}}>props.children</div>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<FooComponent><em>Hi!</em></FooComponent>, targetElement)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this might be helpful.